# Teradata XMLAGG function is not working in snowflake

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Select
ContractVersionId
,Origin
XMLAGG(FIRSTSTATION || '/' ORDER BY FIRSTSTATION) AS InterTransptAndCarrCode
FROM LdCONTRACTMULTISEGMENT
WHERE firstsegair1='AC' AND secondsegair1 <> 'AC'
GROUP BY 1,2,SECONDSEGAIR1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLAGG` is a Teradata function, you can't expect all these functions to work in snowflake as-is. But you're simply trying to get a *group concat* and snowflake supports the Standard SQL function for it:

```
LISTAGG(FIRSTSTATION, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FIRSTSTATION)
```